# Restriction of a div-free vector field to a plane?

Tags: vector-analysis

Suppose we restrict a divergence-free vector field on $\mathbb{R}^3$ to some plane.  What can be said about the restricted vector field?  It no longer has to be divergence-free, of course.  But can *any* vector field on the plane be viewed as the restriction of some div-free field on $\mathbb{R}^3$?  And if not, is there a concise way of characterizing the kinds of fields you can get?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can any vector field on the plane be viewed as the restriction of some div-free field on $\Bbb R^3$?

Yep.  Suppose we are given a $F = [f_x,f_y] : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$.  Define an $\tilde F = [\tilde f_x,\tilde f_y,\tilde f_z]: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ so that $F(x,y) = [\tilde f_x(x,y,0), \tilde f_y (x,y,0)]$ by 
setting:
$\tilde f_x(x,y,z) = f_x(x,y)$
$\tilde f_y(x,y,z) = f_y(x,y)$, and 
$$
f_z(x,y,z) = 
-z\left( \frac{\partial f_x}{\partial x}(x,y) + \frac{\partial f_y}{\partial y}(x,y) \right)
$$
We can quickly verify that $\nabla \cdot \tilde F = 0$.

Comment: "We can quickly": Faster than you can say "verify"! +1

Comment: It looks like I a word :P